# Restfull service only responds to first request

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm dealing with a small web app and having some trouble with XMLHttpRequest. I'm trying to send one POST request and then a GET all towards the same REST endpoint.

I think that the problem is somewhere in the XMLHttp object itself. Maybe the connection from the first is not properly closed.

**First POST request to REST service update news**

```
function send_response(id_str, sentiment) {
    if (glob_id != null) {
        id_str = initial_id
    }
    id = parseInt(id_str)
    if (typeof (id) === 'number' && id > 0 && id < 200000) {
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/update_news', true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        req.send(JSON.stringify({"id": id_str, "sentiment": sentiment}));
        req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    console.log((req.response));
                    glob_id = req.response['id']
                    update_content();
                } else {
                    console.error("Error loading page\n");
                }
            }
        };
    } else {
        console.warn("what are you trying!")
    }
}
```

As you can see, the second HTTP request is triggered once the 200 response code is received. However, even though having stepped into update_content() (function in which the GET request is sent), no request is actually sent.

**Second GET request to the same REST service**

```
function update_content(){
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/update_news', true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    console.log((req.response));
                    document.getElementById("news_content") = req.response['content']
                    glob_id = req.response['id']
                } else {
                    console.error("Error loading page\n");
                }
            }
        };
}
```

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: How do you know no request was sent? Is there no response status code for the second request?

Comment: Just looked into the networking tab of chrome and backend.

Comment: No errors displayed in the console tab? Have you tried logging something in the `update_content()` function to see if it actually gets called?

Comment: I missed the send(), better go to bed jahahaw